# Build an HTML table via two unrelated observableArray objects

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm attempting to use two distinct and unrelated `observableArray` objects to define rows and columns of a table, but I can't figure out if/how to nest the `foreach` bindings together.

The code I'm experimenting on is quite simple ([Fiddle repro here, with some CSS eyecandy](http://jsfiddle.net/e5y6g/)):

```
var vm = function(){
    this.rows = ko.observableArray([1,2,3]);
    this.cols = ko.observableArray(['A', 'B', 'C']);
};
ko.applyBindings(new vm());


<table>
    <tbody>
        <!-- First row: each with a 'cols' value -->
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!-- ko foreach: cols -->
            <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <!-- Subsequent rows: each first with a 'rows' value -->
        <!-- ko foreach: rows -->
        <tr>
            <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
            <!-- ko foreach: cols -->
            <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The ascii-art picture below shows what I'm after, but my markup bindings seem to stop after the first "`empty td`":

```
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│empty th│(th) A  │(th) B  │   ...  │(th) N  │
├────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│(th) 1  │empty td│empty td│   ...  │empty td│
├────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│(th) 2  │empty td│empty td│   ...  │empty td│
├────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│  ...   │   ...  │   ...  │   ...  │   ...  │
├────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│(th) N  │empty td│empty td│   ...  │empty td│ 
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

KO tutorials are very clear but it looks like the two arrays have to be somehow related, also here on SO I found a plethora of questions dealing with objects or array of arrays, that don't seem to apply here...

What am I missing ? It feels like I'm not noticing something obvious.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L9SMW/1/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to refer to the parent element in the following binding :

```
<!-- ko foreach: $parent.cols -->
```

All code :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <!-- First row: each with a 'cols' value -->
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!-- ko foreach: cols -->
            <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <!-- Subsequent rows: each first with a 'rows' value -->
        <!-- ko foreach: rows -->
        <tr>
            <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
            <!-- Refer to $parent--> 
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.cols -->
            <td></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e5y6g/2/)

Comment: I'm sure I tried this already .. Who knows where I mixed up things. Spot on, thanks